# align next to next line

Tags: css, angular-material

How do we set in css that the text should be on the next line?

Output should be like this:
[image]

Current output

```
Financing Contigency Site Plan Approval Contigency
```

Target:

```
Financing Contigency 
Site Plan Approval Contigency
```

Code:

```
<div class="buyer-details-info-field" style="padding-top: 15px;">
     <div class="opacity54">Contingencies</div>
     <span *ngIf="dealData.dealTypeValues.isFinancingContingency" style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Financing Contigency</span>
     <span *ngIf="dealData.dealTypeValues.isSitePlanApprovalContingency" style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Site Plan Approval Contigency</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No Sir , it did not

Comment: how do we break that span  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `display: block` value in your CSS. Here, I apply them for all `<span>`, but you can add it to your `value` css's class.

Also, in this example, I remove the `*ngIf` to make it more clear.

```css
.buyer-details-info-field {
   display: flex;
   height: 28px;
   margin-left: 16px;
   align-items: center;
}

span {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="buyer-details-info-field" style="padding-top: 15px; display: block;">
   <div class="opacity54">Contingencies</div>
   <span style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Financing Contigency</span>
   <span style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Site Plan Approval Contigency</span>
</div>
```

You can also just use `<br>`, with `display: contents` and such as you want to put them on the right, with float: right it's fine :

```css
.buyer-details-info-field {
   display: flex;
   height: 28px;
   margin-left: 16px;
   align-items: center;
}

.value {
   float: right;
}

.opacity54 {
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="buyer-details-info-field" style="padding-top: 15px; display: contents;">
   <div class="opacity54">Contingencies</div>
   <span style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Financing Contigency</span><br>
   <span style="font-size:12px;margin-left: 8px;" class="value">Site Plan Approval Contigency</span>
</div>
```